# PagedList.Mvc sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Using EF in ASP.NET, when paging with `PagedList.Mvc`, I am using in controller sort method by ID:

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
    default:
        wpisy = wpisy.OrderBy(s => s.ID);
        break;
}

int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

return View(wpisy.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

In the `index` view I have:

```
<br /> <br /> Strona @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) z @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {page}))
```

and, with 5 records, it is sorting them:

page I:

```
ID 3
ID 2
ID 1
```

page II:

```
ID 4
ID 5
```

What should I do to have highest ID in top of each page? If I use

```
wpisy = wpisy.OrderByDescending(s => s.ID)
```

then I get :

page I:

```
ID 3
ID 4
ID 5
```

page II:

```
ID 2
ID 1
```

And I want:

page I:

```
ID 5
ID 4
ID 3
```

page II:

```
ID 2
ID 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us how you set `wpisy` variable.

Comment: `wpisy` seems to be a collection, what type it has & how it filled with data?

Comment: Variable: `var wpisy = from s in db.Indeks
                        select s;`